# A java class can't find an other in the same package

Tags: java, class, import, package

I am implementing a java program in ubuntu without an IDE that converts a currency to €, i have 2 classes ConvertiEuro and Valuta both in the same directory (package) called finanza, the class ConvertiEuro uses the class Valuta, when i try to compile Valuta.java it compiles correctly but when i compile ConvertiEuro.java I get an error saying "ConvertiEuro.java:3: error: cannot find symbol" I don't know why here is the code

```
  package finanza;

   public class Valuta {

     private String nomeValuta;
     private double totValuta;



    public Valuta(String nomeVal, double totVal) {

             nomeValuta = nomeVal;
             totValuta = totVal;
   }

       public String getNomeValuta() {

          return nomeValuta;    
       }

        public double getTotValuta() {
          return totValuta;     
   }
```

}

```
package finanza;

 import finanza.Valuta;

 public class ConvertiEuro {


private int valuteGestibili;
private int cont = 0;
private Valuta [] valutas;



public ConvertiEuro(int valuteGest) {

    this.valuteGestibili = valuteGest;
    this.valutas = new Valuta [this.valuteGestibili];


}
public boolean impostaValuta(Valuta val){


    if(cont<valuteGestibili) {
        this.valutas[cont] = val;
        cont ++;
        return true; 

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }   

}

}
```

and this how I compile: javac ConvertiEuro.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem is in how you're compiling.

Both `ConvertiEuro.java` and `Valuta.java` should be in a directory called `finanza`, and you should ideally compile from the *parent* directory, so that all the compiler knows where to find other code in the same package. It would *expect* to find a source file in a `finanza` directory under the one you're currently in, for a package called `finanza`.

It's simplest just to compile all the files at the same time though:

```
javac finanza/*.java
```

... or better yet, use an IDE which will manage this sort of things for you.

Comment: both classes are located in a folder named finanza and when i compile as you indicated it compile correctly even when i delete or comment the import finanza.Valuta; line, and of course it would be easier to use an IDE but i want to learn how to compile and generate jar and javadoc from the command line.